# After changing user directory name Ubuntu stuck at boot

Tags: 14.04, username

I recently bought a new desktop with Ubuntu 14.04 on it. It came with username "user". So I wanted to change the username as well as the name of my home directory.

So I followed the instructions on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_username to do it. I created another user with administrative capabilities. Logged in as that user and did:

```
usermod -l newname oldname
usermod -d /my/new/home username
```

When I logged out and tried to login as the original user, my desktop has been stuck for a day. I've tried hard rebooting it several times, but to no avail.

I am not sure what is going on. Can you please help me to fix it?

Comment: I know I should have just created a new user for myself and copied the files. However the wiki page didn't give any warning and now I am extremely stressed about this situation. Please help me!

Comment: If it's not solved yet, then more information would be required, such as `grep "your-username" /etc/passwd` (no sensitive information is provided) and `ls -l /home`.

Comment: I have deleted the problematic user by using `userdel` command. Now there is only one user "guest" (with administrative capabilities though). 
`grep guest /etc/passwd` gives `guest:x:1001:1001:Guest,,,:/home/guest:/bin/bash
`ls -l /home` gives 
`total 24
drwxr-xr-x 21 guest guest 4096   May 21 10:42 guest
drwx------- 18 root    root   16384 May 12 14:37 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 30  1000 user   4096   May 20 17:07 user`
`user` was the home directory of problematic user which I deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so considering what you have now here's what I would do:

```
# adduser "your-new-username"
# mv /home/user /home/"your-new-username"
# chown "your-new-username":"your-new-username" /home/"your-new-username" -R
```

Reboot, and try to login again.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted, you seem to be missing the last detail:

`# usermod -m -d /my/new/home username`

This will move the data from your old home to the new home (and create the new dir, if it doesn't exist already).

The last command you issued probably did not create a new directory in the filsesystem with your username. Therefore, when you try to login, the new home dir does not exist for your user, and login fails.

Comment: I guess that could be the problem. However the wiki says:
"You do not need to manually create the new directory. The move is fully automatic. " I tried changing the home directory back to the original one but it still gets stuck at the boot

Comment: That's right, but doing the step mentioned above, is what automatically creates your new home dir.